# How to pass a string + web url and receive the response using python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-translate

I'm using Python and Google Translate. When I click on Listen while translating, a sound file is generated and a URL is passed like so: `http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=text`.

I want to generate URLs locally using Python then send them to the web and receive these sound files from Google Translate. I tried a lot of URLlib2 and URLparse but I have no clue about what I need to do to make this work.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Generating the URLs? Getting the response from the Web? Handling the response?

Comment: I think the bigger question here is "does Google Translate allow you to do something like this to begin with?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the user-agent so that the website thinks you are connecting with a browser. Try the following bit of code:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=text"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0') 
opener = urllib2.build_opener()

f = open("data.mp3", "wb")
f.write(opener.open(request).read())
f.close()
```