# MP3 file downloaded through Python with urllib is unplayable, works fine in browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

This is a link to an MP3 file: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=je/, and it downloads just fine. But when I try to use the following code to download it, I get a file that Windows Media Player and VLC refuse to play. Here is my code (I tested two methods):

```
import urllib

query = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=je/"
urllib.urlretrieve(query, "je.mp3")

mp3file = urllib.urlopen(query)
output = open('je2.mp3','wb')
output.write(mp3file.read())
output.close()
mp3file.close()
```

Both of the files do not play. I have a feeling this has something to do with the file I am using, because [other ones](http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/Toccata-and-Fugue-Dm.mp3) seem to work fine (Something to do with the query string perhaps). Any help? I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 8

Comment: If other files work...?? Have you looked at the file raw contents to see if they are different when downloaded that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226167/how-to-pass-a-string-web-url-and-receive-the-response-using-python).

In short, the page won't let you download any sound file unless you modify the headers the program sends, so it looks like the program is actually a browser.